# Kie Business Central Installation Failed

Tags: java, jboss, drools, kie, kie-workbench

I try to install Business Workbench downloaded from [drools site here](https://www.drools.org/download/download.html)
into latest WildFly server but always failed with below error:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"business-central.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KeyCloakUserManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCCredentialsUserManagementService(KeyCloakUserManager, KeyCloakGroupManager, CredentialsClientFactory, @Named UberfireRoleManager)
  at org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCCredentialsUserManagementService.<init>(KCCredentialsUserManagementService.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KeyCloakUserManager is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure from [Module \"deployment.business-central.war\" from Service Module Loader].

    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KeyCloakGroupManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCAdapterUserManagementService(KeyCloakUserManager, KeyCloakGroupManager, KCAdapterClientFactory, HttpServletRequest, @Named UberfireRoleManager)
  at org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCAdapterUserManagementService.<init>(KCAdapterUserManagementService.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KeyCloakGroupManager is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure from [Module \"deployment.business-central.war\" from Service Module Loader].

    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.9.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

Please I need some help on how to deploy this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried providing the jar with the missing class?

Comment: Hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas hmmm I really thought when they said its FINAL, and compatible with Wildfly, they should've mean it..

Comment: FINAL is part of the build number (compare to beta, alpha, rc, etc.) Just means it's the final release for that version number. And it can be compatible with Wildfly and still require you to, you know, _configure your wildfly server properly_. Should check that the jar is still part of Wildfly -- it used to be (Wildfly 10, 16, etc. is where I spotchecked) but it may not be in newer ones.